# Ensuring execution order between multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, deadlock, race-condition

I am having a kinda annoying problem mostly due to my low skill level/experience in C# multithreading.

Here is the background. In my framework, I have a static class named `WaitFormHelper`, which has two static methods (well... actually more but we don't care here), `Start()` and `Close()`
The `Start()` method initializes and starts a thread which will acquire a lock on the `locker` object and create a `WaitForm` (which is a small loading control with a custom message and a progress bar)

In my current project, I have a method which starts a `WaitForm`, performs calculations, then closes the `WaitForm`. Nothing fancy at all.
The method looks like the following, I simplified it as much as possible:

```
public void PerformCalculations()
{
   try
   {
      WaitFormHelper.Start("Title", "message", false);
      if (this.CalculationsParameters.IsInvalid)
      {
         return;
      }
      // Perform all those lengthy calculations here
   } 
   // catch whatever exception I may have to catch, we don't care here
   finally
   {
      WaitFormHelper.Close();
   }
}
```

Here are the `Start()` and `Close()` methods with related methods & attributes, simplified as well:

```
private static Thread instanceCaller;
private static WaitForm instance;

private static AutoResetEvent waitFormStarted = new AutoResetEvent(false);
private static object locker = new object();

/// <summary>
/// Initializes WaitForm to start a single task
/// </summary>
/// <param name="header">WaitForm header</param>
/// <param name="message">Message displayed</param>
/// <param name="showProgressBar">True if we want a progress bar, else false</param>
public static void Start(string header, string message, bool showProgressBar)
{
    InitializeCallerThread(showProgressBar, header, message);
    instanceCaller.Start();
}

/// <summary>
/// Initializes caller thread for executing a single command
/// </summary>
/// <param name="showProgressBar"></param>
/// <param name="header"></param>
/// <param name="message"></param>
private static void InitializeCallerThread(bool showProgressBar, string header, string message)
{
    waitFormStarted.Reset();

    instanceCaller = new Thread(() =>
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            instance = new WaitForm()
            {
                Header = header,
                Message = message,
                IsProgressBarVisible = showProgressBar
            };
            waitFormStarted.Set();
        }
        instance.ShowDialog();
    });
    instanceCaller.Name = "WaitForm thread";
    instanceCaller.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    instanceCaller.IsBackground = true;
}

/// <summary>
/// Closes current form
/// </summary>
public static void Close()
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        if (instance != null && !instance.IsClosed)
        {
            waitFormStarted.WaitOne();
            instance.FinalizeWork();
            instance.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                new Action(() =>
                {
                    instance.Close();
                }));
        }
    }
}
```

**Now let's get to the problem**

This usually works fine, except in this case:
If `this.CalculationsParameters.IsInvalid` is true (ie. as you probably already understood, I can't perform calculations for some reason, such as "user entering crap in my forms"), the execution directly closes my `WaitForm`.
However in this case, the main thread will reach the `Close` method and acquire a lock on the `locker` object **before** the thread fired by the `Start()` method.

What happens is that: `Close` acquires lock, tries to close the form but `instance` is still null because the `Thread` created in `InitializeCallerThread` is still waiting for the lock to actually create it. `Close` releases lock, `InitializeCallerThread` acquires it and... shows a `WaitForm` which will not close.

Now I know that I can simply fix this problem by testing if the calculation parameters are invalid before actually starting the WaitForm, but well, problem is this `WaitForm` is supposed to be used by all applications of our framework (which includes 40+ different apps used and maintained in 4 countries), so ideally I'd rather prefer seeing my `WaitForm` working at all cases.

Do you have any idea on how could I synchronize this to make sure the starter thread is definitely called and executed first?
As you can see I already use an `AutoResetEvent` for this matter, but if I listen to it before the test `if (instance != null)` I will end up stuck in my case.

Hope this is clear enough! Thank you!

Comment: Why create a secondary UI thread just to display a "busy dialog"? Such a thing should be executed as a modal dialog on the primary UI thread to block UI interaction on existing Forms. Background calculations should not occur on the primary thread, but rather in a background thread, thread pool, or BackgroundWorker.

Comment: I actually have 2 ways of using the `WaitForm`: first is calling `Start(header, message, delegate)` which will as you said execute the calculations defined in the delegate in a background thread. Second is the one I'm showing here, and has mostly been implemented to make sure we can replace our old `WinForms` WaitForm (which was working this way... and I had the same reaction as yours) with this new WPF version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some mechanism to make a "queue control", coordinating steps according to the order you want them occurring.

Recently I have needed to implement something like this to force a specific order in the execution of several threads in a unit test.

Here is my suggestion:

**QueueSynchronizer:**

```
/// <summary>
/// Synchronizes steps between threads.
/// </summary>
public class QueueSynchronizer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="minWait">Minimum waiting time until the next try.</param>
    /// <param name="maxWait">Maximum waiting time until the next try.</param>
    public QueueSynchronizer(Int32 minWait, Int32 maxWait)
    {
    }

    private Mutex mx = new Mutex();
    /// <summary>
    /// Minimum waiting time until the next try.
    /// </summary>
    private Int32 minWait = 5;
    /// <summary>
    /// Maximum waiting time until the next try.
    /// </summary>
    private Int32 maxWait = 500;

    int currentStep = 1;

    /// <summary>
    /// Key: order in the queue; Value: Time to wait.
    /// </summary>
    private Dictionary<int, int> waitingTimeForNextMap = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Synchronizes by the order in the queue. It starts from 1. If is not 
    /// its turn, the thread waits for a moment, after that, it tries again, 
    /// and so on until its turn.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="orderInTheQueue">Order in the queue. It starts from 1.</param>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="Mutex"/>The mutex that must be released at the end of turn.
    /// </returns>
    public Mutex Sincronize(int orderInTheQueue)
    {
        do
        {
            //while it is not the turn, the thread will stay in this loop and sleeping for 100, 200, ... 1000 ms
            if (orderInTheQueue != this.currentStep)
            {
                //The next in queue will be waiting here (other threads).
                mx.WaitOne();
                mx.ReleaseMutex();

                //Prevents 100% processing while the current step does not happen
                if (!waitingTimeForNextMap.ContainsKey(orderInTheQueue))
                {
                    waitingTimeForNextMap[orderInTheQueue] = this.minWait;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(waitingTimeForNextMap[orderInTheQueue]);
                waitingTimeForNextMap[orderInTheQueue] = Math.Min(waitingTimeForNextMap[orderInTheQueue] * 2, this.maxWait);
            }
        } while (orderInTheQueue != this.currentStep);

        mx.WaitOne();
        currentStep++;
        return mx;
    }
}
```

`Start()` and `Close()` with `QueueSynchronizer`:

```
//synchronizer
private static QueueSynchronizer queueSynchronizer;

private static Thread instanceCaller;
private static WaitForm instance;

private static AutoResetEvent waitFormStarted = new AutoResetEvent(false);
private static object locker = new object();

/// <summary>
/// Initializes WaitForm to start a single task
/// </summary>
/// <param name="header">WaitForm header</param>
/// <param name="message">Message displayed</param>
/// <param name="showProgressBar">True if we want a progress bar, else false</param>
public static void Start(string header, string message, bool showProgressBar)
{
    queueSynchronizer = new QueueSynchronizer();
    InitializeCallerThread(showProgressBar, header, message);
    instanceCaller.Start();
}

/// <summary>
/// Initializes caller thread for executing a single command
/// </summary>
/// <param name="showProgressBar"></param>
/// <param name="header"></param>
/// <param name="message"></param>
private static void InitializeCallerThread(bool showProgressBar, string header, string message)
{
    waitFormStarted.Reset();

    instanceCaller = new Thread(() =>
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            //Queuing to run on first.
            Mutex mx = queueSynchronizer.Sincronize(1);
            try
            {
                instance = new WaitForm()
                        {
                            Header = header,
                            Message = message,
                            IsProgressBarVisible = showProgressBar
                        };
            }
            finally
            {
                //I think is here that ends the first step!?
                mx.ReleaseMutex();
            }

            waitFormStarted.Set();
        }
        instance.ShowDialog();
    });
    instanceCaller.Name = "WaitForm thread";
    instanceCaller.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    instanceCaller.IsBackground = true;
}

/// <summary>
/// Closes current form
/// </summary>
public static void Close()
{
    //Queuing to run on second.
    Mutex mx = queueSynchronizer.Sincronize(2);
    try
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            if (instance != null && !instance.IsClosed)
            {
                waitFormStarted.WaitOne();
                instance.FinalizeWork();
                instance.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                    new Action(() =>
                    {
                        instance.Close();
                    }));
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        mx.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a good idea. I was hesitating to go on this direction, feels like a lot of code for what seems like a basic need, I'd have thought that this kind of stuff is built-in. Well. Guess I'll try this first

Answer (score 0):

You need to Join on the thread that you created.  By joining on a thread you'll block at that point until the thread has finished executing.

```
public static void Close()
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        instanceCaller.Join();

        if (instance != null && !instance.IsClosed)
        {
            waitFormStarted.WaitOne();
            instance.FinalizeWork();
            instance.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                new Action(() =>
                {
                    instance.Close();
                }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do the Join after acquiring the lock on `locker`, I'll probably end up stuck since the caller thread can't be executed, right?

Comment: Oh, and instanceCaller calls ShowDialog() so will most likely not join unless we actually close the form!

Comment: @Damascus Yes, it is possible for the acquire the lock on the locker before the thread does itself, so you could move the Join to outside of the locker.  Or you could add another lock for access to the thread object to provide synchronization for creating and stopping the thread.  There is also the possibility of the thread object being null which will need to be handled.  And yes, the instanceCaller.Join will block until the dialog has been closed.

Comment: Hm. Although the Join won't help me in this case (the dialog is only closed in this Close method), you gave me an idea with using another object to lock access to the thread. I'll try this and see what happens